# Custom JPA Fetch Size on spring boot application not working on IBM liberty core

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

In application (Spring boot + Spring data + JPA[hibernate] + Oracle), we defined below property of fetch size in application.properties file.

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 500

The above property working on the embedded tomcat container. But once we deployed the application on websphere liberty core server. It always taking the default fetch size i.e. 1. The container not recognized the defined property.

Application is running on JNDI configuration. And JNDI configuration defined in server.xml of liberty. Below is the code snippet.

```
<application id="Example" location="C:/Example.ear" name="Example" type="ear" />

<authData id="auth1" password="dev123" user="dev"/>
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/example" type="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//s123456.fr.net.intra:1521/test" databaseName="test" driverType="thin" password="dev123" portNumber="1521" serverName="s123456.fr.net.intra" user="dev"/>
</dataSource>
<resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/example" name="jdbc/example">
    <authentication-alias name="auth1"/>
</resource-ref>enter code here
```

As per my findings we can set the fetch size for db2 and informix but didn't find  it for properties.oracle, as mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_core.html#mtFile128)

Fetch size property as mentioned above worked if I Retrieve data using entity manager as,

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee");
query.list();
```

But I don't want to go with entity manager, as we used spring data for application.

How can I set the fetch size in liberty core for spring boot with spring data application?

Answer (score 2):

The properties.* configuration elements in Liberty expose configuration of a particular JDBC vendor's data source implementation.  The reason that properties.db2.jcc and properties.informix.jcc have a fetchSize attribute is that the JDBC driver's data source itself supports configuration of a default fetchSize at the DataSource level via get/setFetchSize methods.  Oracle JDBC driver does not have these methods on its data source, which is why properties.oracle lacks this configuration.  (Note that if a newer version of Oracle JDBC driver did add the methods, you could included the fetchSize="500" attribute on properties.oracle even though the schema does not have it, and Liberty would send it to the Oracle JDBC driver, but currently there are no such methods on the Oracle JDBC driver for Liberty to invoke)

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size in application.properties looks to be a Spring-specific way of configuring the Hibernate attribute.
This would be implemented within Hibernate, presumably by it using java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize(value) on the java.sql.Statement objects that it obtains after obtaining them from the JDBC driver.

It looks like Hibernate documentation has a property of its own for this purpose,

```
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size
```

which is documented here,
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-jdbc-properties

which you should hopefully be able to use to configure the value rather than the Spring-specific approach.

Comment: I agree with your approach but using a hibernate property would not work as the application configured with spring data.

Comment: Now I am trying to change the **classloader** of the application as, '<application id="Example" location="C:/Example.ear" name="Example" type="ear"> <classloader delegation="parentLast" /> </application>'. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

I have came across the same situation on my project and we found that it is nothing to do with the liberty or project configuration. The actual issue is with the logging which impacts the performance and we did below changes in the logback.xml to make all the logging asynchronous.

Check the below code snippet to make logs asynchronous,

```
<appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/project.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC_All" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_All" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have multiple logging in the project like file logs and syslogs. After adding AsyncAppender there is a drastic change in the performance.